# Can I put a function inside a struct?

Tags: c

Maybe I use inline functions...
There are any way to archieve it, without using function pointers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Put a function inside a struct"? What's that supposed to mean?

Comment: For my purposes, is not he same thing...

Comment: Why you don't want function pointer ? If you need ANY function in struct - then just save `void*`. And later typecast it into function required ...

Answer (score 5):

Not in C.  You can in C++.  A struct is just a class with all members being public by default in that language.

Answer (score 4):

No, structure supports only a pointer to a function.

Answer (score 3):

Not in C.  But you can in C++.

Answer (score 1):

No

The only way I can think of is similar to [this one](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dbopen) (with function pointers).

Answer (score 1):

to complement all other answers, i would add that a, in C, a structure is only for storing data: a function is not data, so it cannot be stored into a structure.

however, as pcent pointed out, a pointer to a function is a type of data and can be stored in a structure.